# using the same webpart logic with different look in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2010, web-parts

I have a custom developed webpart in Visual studio, and I want to use this same functionality in my sharepoint site multiple times but with different looks every time.

what's the best practice to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would suggest used xslt based custom webpart so that you can apply different xslt on each instance to get different look and feel good example for the same is sharepoint coreresult webpart.

You have to inherit your webpart from  [DataFormWebPart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.dataformwebpart_methods.aspx)